# Piercing the Earth

Tags: earth, weapon-mass-destruction

How much force, momentum, and energy would be needed to have an object pierce through the Earth? I've tried to research this, but I could not find results for a mathematical value.

Assume the Earths density is uniform, with the average density of the actual Earth, and that the object piercing the Earth is a sphere with a radius of 1 meter made of an indestructible material. Would it be possible to find mathematical values (force, momentum, energy) for such an event? Thank you for any help.

Comment: How dense is the Earth? You say it's uniform but are you just using the existing average or do you have specifics in mind?

Comment: I apologize for not including that detail, I ment uniform density as in the average density

Comment: 0.32 eV which is the approximated mass of all 3 flavors of neutrinos combined.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you couldn't *pierce* the Earth, it would disintegrate and much of the molten remnants might re-agglomerate and eventually form a solid crust.

Comment: Given the mass and density of the Earth, I suspect the real answer would be to use something very exotic like a quark nugget, cosmic string or micro black hole to actually pierce the Earth.

Comment: This may have been answered already: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/50772/what-type-of-celestial-body-could-pierce-an-earth-like-planet-without-loss-of-tr/50810#50810

Comment: I recommend reading [this](https://what-if.xkcd.com/39/) for a bit of an explanation of why this question doesn't really make sense from a physics point of view (specifically the last half)

Answer (score 4):

Not enough data.

Energy will depend on a lot of factors - how slippery is the object, how fast it moves, a viscosity of earth, something I do not know. This will be a reason that you will not find some particular number or formula for the general situation.

Bare minimum(for very slow moving object, very slippery one, which negates viscosity for surrounding area)- it is energy needed to place 1m round object into the core of the Earth. The pressure in the core is about 360 GPa, so it is about 1.5072e+12 J . If this object has Iron density the energy is equivalent to its kinetic energy at 10'141 m/s. Or it is 418'666 kWh.

More realistic bare minimum - it is how much energy it is needed to create tunnel trough earth, with 1m radius along the tunnel.

I'm a bit lazy to integrate, so next step same tunnel with a bit of friction during the creation - I take average pressure as (360GPa+0GPa)/2=180GPa.

Tunnel 12'740km long, radius 1m -> 7.200648e+18J
For indestructible, slippery, slow moving iron ball it will be equivalent of its kinetic energy at speed 21'432'953 m/s, or 2'000'180 GWh

Just creating a tunnel needs less energy than those 2'000'180 GWh (with 0 viscosity).

Fast moving object penetrating the Earth will need more energy than those 2'000'180 GWh, because it supply significant impulse to all matter it goes trough, a round object is not ideal in this situation, a cube heading toward to core with its corner(one of 8, not one of 12) will set the speed of surrounding matter almost same (a bit less) as one at which it moves itself.

A cone with 4m height and 1m radius of the base will set the speed of surrounding matter as 1/4 of its speed.

So bare minimum energy will be speed of matter from that tunnel at 1/4 (for a cone, not sphere) kinetic energy of that matter at 1/4 speed of the cone.

Average density of earth is 5510kg/m<sup>3</sup>, and if cone moves with velocity 21'432'953 m/s it will be $\frac {5510 \cdot 12740000 \cdot (\frac{v}{4})^2}{2}\approx$ 1.0e+24 J

Volume of the cone is almost same as of the sphere 4.19 vs 4.18 m<sup>3</sup>
And for indestructible Iron cone it will be equivalent to its kinetic energy at 8'008'384'022 m/s or about 26 speed of light in terms of classical mechanics which is obviously not works, but let say it was approximation of cone speed, now we know it have to be about speed of light, so we recalculate.

Average density of earth is 5510kg/m<sup>3</sup>, and if cone moves with velocity 0.9..$c$ it will be $\frac {5510 \cdot 12740000 \cdot (\frac{c}{4})^2}{2}\approx$ 1.974e+26J

It is equivalent to the [relativistic kinetic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Relativistic_kinetic_energy_of_rigid_bodies) of the indestructible Iron cone at speed of about 0.9999999998973 speed of light.

Energy is significantly less than estimated Earth gravity binding energy in [Earth's Gravitational Binding Energy, Dave Typinski](http://typnet.net/Essays/EarthBind.htm) as -1.711×10<sup>32</sup>J, so the planet will be fine, still a planet.

But who know that everything is for absolute slippery cone, and I counted only one component of impulse(radial one) of matter from tunnel, so basically calculations are incorrect, but I guess planet will still be a planet, maybe real value will be about order of magnitude more, wild guess, maybe two orders of magnitude, still not enough to destroy it.

Comment: I did not think to add in conditions such as mass,  although it does make sense when you mention it. I used the situation of an indestructible sphere because I thought it would be the most simplistic scenario, but I guess I assumed wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, when you had (v/4) in the equation, was the denomenator found by the height /diameter, (4/1) ? Or was it just the height of the cone?

Comment: @TheOneAndOnlyOne height/radius .  Each height traveled it displaces matter at distance 1 radius from the axis of cone and that defines the speed, if to neglect that it pushes this matter forward too. this way real speed something in between projectile speed and 1/4, but closer to 1/4 I guess.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the explanation. @MolbOrg

Answer (score 1):

Newton says your penetrator must be degenerate.

The problem is that when a high speed projectile plows into something it's going to be basically stopped in the distance where it has displaced mass equal to it's own mass.

The only way you'll get that kind of mass is with degenerate matter or else with something traveling so close to lightspeed that the energy liberated by it's passage blows the planet apart rather than drilling a hole.

Note, also, that your hole will promptly close behind the projectile.

Comment: Second paragraph is false. Try shooting wooden arrow into a lake. It will **not** stop on the surface, unless you have really weak bow. It will go down, possibly a meter or few, and only then float up. It will stop when it's kinetic energy is exhausted and that's all.

Comment: You are missing the fact that the arrow has length.  Of course it penetrates a bit.  For a video of what I'm talking about look for video of guns shooting into water/being fired underwater.  Bigger bullets go a bit farther (unless they shatter) because they're longer but they all stop quickly.

Comment: No, I'm not missing anything. Arrow goes down way, way deeper than about half of it's length when you shoot it straight down. And it depends more on drag than on buoyancy. Test it, if you don't believe me.

Comment: A quick perusal of a table of wood densities shows an average of around 70% and I would think an arrow would be made of a stronger (denser) wood than average.  Furthermore, they have metal tips.  I would **expect** penetration to more than half it's depth.

Comment: Note that Newton's answer (which holds up well even today) is for projectiles moving fast enough that the cohesion of the object penetrated can be ignored.